# Trigger click in jQuery

Tags: jquery, triggers, click

I must be overlooking something simple, but I just don't get it.

I'm trying to trigger a click on a hyperlink in a listitem.

**JS**

```
(function($) {
    $('li').click(function() {
        var li = $(this);

        var link = $('a', li);

        link.click();
    });
})(jQuery);
```

**html**

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="http://example.com" target="_blank">TEST</a></li>
</ul>
```

When I run the above code on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CKucA/2/) I get an error:

```
<error>
jQuery.event.dispatch
jQuery.event.add.elemData.handle.eventHandle
jQuery.event.trigger
jQuery.fn.extend.trigger
jQuery.extend.each
jQuery.fn.jQuery.each
jQuery.fn.extend.trigger
jQuery.each.jQuery.fn.(anonymous function)
(anonymous function)
jQuery.event.dispatch
jQuery.event.add.elemData.handle.eventHandle
jQuery.event.trigger
jQuery.fn.extend.trigger
jQuery.extend.each
jQuery.fn.jQuery.each
jQuery.fn.extend.trigger
...
```

So I want to trigger the click on the hyperlink when user clicks on listitem.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
(function($) {
    $('li').click(function(e) {
        var li = $(this);

        if ( !$(e.target).is('a') ){
            var link = $('a', li);
            window.open(link.attr('href'), link.attr('target'));
        }
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Test:
http://jsfiddle.net/vFZ3Z/1/

Comment: doesn't open the link when clicked on li

Comment: It works for me. give me details about your browser version and jquery version you used.

Comment: although the above works (now). I want to create something generic (not in the question I know, my bad). `target` can be anything (frames, new window, etc) or the target could just not be there. Your code always opens a new window. I know I could check if `taregt` attr exists but I thought it would be much simpler to just trigger the click. Looks like I was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you're being prevented from triggering a hyperlink click as a browser security feature. Try using JavaScript to explicitly open the window instead:

```
(function($) {
    $('li').click(function(e) {
        var link = $(this).find('a');
        link.click();
    });
    $('a').click(function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        var href = $(this).attr('href');
        var tgt = $(this).attr('target');
        window.open(href,tgt);
        return false;
    });
})(jQuery);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/CKucA/15/

Comment: @PeeHaa What browser are you using? It works perfectly for me.

Comment: I noticed you're not using a `$(document).ready` wrapper in your code here; this might be causing trouble for you in your page. http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/CKucA/17/

Comment: `(function($) { })(jQuery);` is the same but better :-)

Comment: @PeeHaa Actually, it's not -- look at http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/CKucA/18/ compared to 17 -- the click handler doesn't attach because it runs before the DOM is loaded.